# If $\vert x - a \vert < \frac{1}{2}\vert a\vert$, then $\frac{1}{2}\vert a\vert < \vert x \vert$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

I'm reading a proof, and I cannot figure out why the following is true:

If $\vert x - a \vert < \frac{1}{2}\vert a\vert$, then $\frac{1}{2}\vert a\vert < \vert x \vert$

(x and a are reals, of course). I've tried using the triangle inequality every which way, but I just can't prove the result. Please prove that the statement is correct.

Edit: Apologies. Changed the first ">" to "<".

Comment: Please, please use MathJax.  `$|x-a|$` will get you $|x-a|$, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: $a=4$, $x=1$, $|x-a| = 3 > 2 = \frac 12 |a|$, but $\frac12 |a| \ge |x|$.

Comment: @peterwhy  thank you, I figured this had to be false.

Comment: A simpler counter-example is $x=0$ and $a\not=0$.

Comment: @awllower  lol, so obvious.

Comment: Apologies. One of my signs is pointing the wrong way. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\vert x-a\vert<\frac12\vert a\vert$ is equivalent with
$$a-\frac12\vert a\vert < x<a+\frac12\vert a \vert.$$
If $a>=0$ then $\vert a\vert= a$ so 
$$\frac12\vert a\vert<x<\frac32\vert a\vert.$$
If $a<0$ then $\vert a\vert= -a$ so 
$$\frac32a<x<\frac12 a.$$
And hence $x<0$, so $\vert x\vert = -x$. Thus
$$\frac12\vert a\vert<\vert x\vert<\frac32\vert a\vert.$$

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect!

Answer (score 3):

This will help immensely! I present the *reverse triangle inequality:* For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x-y| \geq |x|-|y|$. Notice that since $|x-y|=|y-x|$, this is equivalent to saying $|x-y| \geq |y|-|x|$.

Proof: The triangle inequality says $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$ for all real $a,b.$ Apply this to $a = y-x$ and $b = x$. Then, subtract $|a|$ from both sides of the inequality. Finally, use that $|a|=|-a|$.

How this helps: we have $|a|/2 > |x-a| \geq |a|-|x|$. Then, add $|x|$ to both sides and subtract $|a|/2.$

Comment: This is very elegant, and now I realize that the extreme left side of the triangle equality is true even without the absolute value sign around the other absolute value signs (which is obvious once you think about it, I suppose).

Comment: Glad you like it. I obviously didn't invent that or anything, but I use extremely often, and I can't fathom why it is not presented in most texts. What do you mean, though, by "the extreme left side of the triangle equality is true even without the absolute value sign around the other absolute value signs?"

Comment: What I mean is that what you refer to as the "reverse triangle inequality" is just one side of the triangle inequality in my real analysis book, except that in my book, there is an absolute sign enclosing the whole expression instead of just x and y individually, as you have stated it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think I have seen that. In that case this follows because $|x| \geq x$ is always true (and also useful). So, in reality, what your book states is stronger than the reverse triangle inequality, but arguably not as useful.

Comment: True, true. That's why I wrote on my initial comment to you, "now I realize that the extreme left side of the triangle equality is true even without the absolute value sign around the other absolute value signs." But now we're just splitting hairs, I think. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If $a\ne 0$ then we have:

Remember that $$a^2\leq b^2\iff |a|\leq |b|$$
so we might square first inequality:

$$(x - a)^2< \frac{1}{4}a^2$$ then $$(2x-3a)(2x-a)<0$$ so, if $a>0$ then  $$x\in ({a\over 2},{3a\over 2})\implies |x|>{|a|\over 2}$$

and if $a<0$ then  $$x\in ({3a\over 2},{a\over 2})\implies |x|>{|a|\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, suppose that a is positive.  Then we can rewrite the first statement as

-a/2 < x - a < a/2

so that

a/2 < x < 3a/2

The left hand side here is what we want.

Comment: The statement has to be proven regardless of whether a is positive, however.

Comment: Both expressions are invariant under negating both x and a, so we can take a positive WLOG.  Or if that's too fancy for you you can just work out the case where a is negative separately by the same means.